# Create custom directory role from MS graph or Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-rbac, azure-identity

I want to create custom directory role with specific permissions like:

```
microsoft.directory/users/*
microsoft.directory/groups/*
microsoft.directory/applications/*
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/*
```

If I create role from Portal, it  asks me to select each and every permission manually to add. But I want to automate that from MS graph or PowerShell.

Suppose if I give `microsoft.directory/users/*` in the code, it should automatically select all permissions related to users.

Is this possible in any way?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same. Gave commands to create custom role  with `"microsoft.directory/users/*"`

But its giving error as Property set is required for task 'any'

[image]

**If you want all the user permissions to be given then you can assign the User Account Administrator role which has the following user permssions:**

```
microsoft.directory/users/assignLicense
microsoft.directory/users/create
microsoft.directory/users/delete
microsoft.directory/users/disable
microsoft.directory/users/enable
microsoft.directory/users/inviteGuest
microsoft.directory/users/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
microsoft.directory/users/reprocessLicenseAssignment
microsoft.directory/users/restore
microsoft.directory/users/basic/update
microsoft.directory/users/manager/update
microsoft.directory/users/password/update
microsoft.directory/users/photo/update
microsoft.directory/users/userPrincipalName/update
```

[image]

**You can assign that role to the user which includes all those permissions:**

[image]

**User assigned to required role:**

[image]